# how to access child node from node in htmlagility pack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

```js
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="submain"><h2></h2><p></p><ul></ul>
            </div>
            <div class="submain"><h2></h2><p></p><ul></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I loaded the html into an `HtmlDocument`. Then I selected the XPath as `submain`. Then I dont know how to access to each tags i.e `h2`, `p` separately.

```js
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class=\"submain\"]");
foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node in nodes) {}
```

If I Use `node.InnerText` I get all the texts and `InnerHtml` is also not useful. How to select separate tags?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The following will help:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class=\"submain\"]");
foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node in nodes) {
    //Do you say you want to access to <h2>, <p> here?
    //You can do:
    HtmlNode h2Node = node.SelectSingleNode("./h2"); //That will get the first <h2> node
    HtmlNode allH2Nodes= node.SelectNodes(".//h2"); //That will search in depth too

    //And you can also take a look at the children, without using XPath (like in a tree):        
    HtmlNode h2Node = node.ChildNodes["h2"];
}
```

Comment: thanks for syntax ```node.SelectSingleNode("./h2")```

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for Descendants

```
var firstSubmainNodeName = doc
   .DocumentNode
   .Descendants()
   .Where(n => n.Attributes["class"].Value == "submain")
   .First()
   .InnerText;
```

Answer (score 2):

From memory, I believe that each `Node` has its own `ChildNodes` collection, so within your `for…each` block you should be able to inspect `node.ChildNodes`.