# How to get first tag in a list?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

suppose I have the following list:

```
<div id='page_competition_1_block_competition_left_tree_2'>
    <div>   
       <ul> 
          <li>
              <a href="#" />
              <ul>
                  <li>
                      <a href="#">
                   </li>
               </ul>
           </li>
           <li>
               <a href="#" />
            ...
```

how can I get the first `a` tag for each `li`?

I tried using:

```
HtmlNodeCollection compsLi = doc.DocumentNode             
.SelectNodes("div[@id='page_match_1_block_competition_left_tree_2']//div//ul/li[1]");
```

but this will return null

Comment: Eh, the id in your code does not match the one in the example. The xml has "page_competition_1_block_competition_left_tree_2". The code has "page_match_1_block_competition_left_tree_2".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a single `/` instead of `//`, so:

```
HtmlNodeCollection compsLi = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("div[@id='page_match_1_block_competition_left_tree_2']//ul/li/a");
```

Essentially:

`/`: search for the current node.

`//`: search from the root document node.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to iterate through the `compsLi` object you retrieve.  Additionally, I don't think you need the `[1]` in your selector.  Once you get the `<li>` item you should be able to do something like this:

```
foreach(var node in compsLi)
{
  var aNode = node.SelectSingleNode("./a");
  ...
}
```

You can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282536/how-to-access-child-node-from-node-in-htmlagility-pack) for something similar.

Comment: yes, but I want prevent to take in the xpath query also the unnecessary tag